# Stop deducting values in a row from a cell when it is about to reach zero

Tags: excel

Consider the data below (assuming all are in row 1):

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
20  7   3   4   3   8   7
```

What I want to do is to deduct from A1 the values in row 1, starting from the rightmost value (G1) going to the left (ending in B1). Once the value is about to produce a negative result, I want it to stop deducting from there. In the given example, the formula should have a step-by-step approach like this:

```
A1-G1 (20-7) = 13
A1-G1-F1 (13-8) = 5
A1-G1-F1-E1 (5-3) = 2
A1-G1-F1-E1-D1 (2-4) = -2
```

In the third step, once it detects that deducting the fourth value (D1) will result to negative, it will stop deducting from there and the formula should result to a value of 2.

There are two things I did for this:

1. I used a long multiple IF statement with the following pattern:

   `=A1-IF(A1-G1<0,0,G1)-IF(A1-G1-F1<0,0,F1)....`
2. I used a helper column in cell B2 going to G2 with the following formula entered in B2 and dragged to the right:

   `=IF(A1-SUM(B1:$G$1)<0,0,A1-SUM(B1:$G$1))`

After which, I simply used the `MIN()` function to get the desired value.

Now, the problem with this is I had to do this for some hundred to thousand rows, and that values will keep on being added on the right most cells for all rows. What I thought of doing was to dedicate a helper sheet linked to my original data and use the second option to get the minimum value. I can just link the column letter in the `SUM()` function by using `COUNTIF`, `ADDRESS`, `SUBSTITUTE` and `INDIRECT` methods, which I believe will work fine. I was just wondering if I can avoid all these works and use instead a single formula to achieve my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: You could create a VBA solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can see an offset solution where you start by subtracting the total of the numbers (32) from the first number (20) to get a negative number (-12), then start adding in the numbers 7, 7+3, 7+3+4 … until you get a positive number (+2). It would look like this (entered as an array formula):

```
=INDEX((A1-SUM(B1:G1)+SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,0,1,1,COLUMN(B1:G1)-1))),
MATCH(TRUE,(A1-SUM(B1:G1)+SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,0,1,1,COLUMN(B1:G1)-1)))>0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enter as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

`=MIN(IFERROR(SQRT(A1-MMULT(IF(COLUMN(B1:G1)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:G1)),B1:G1,0),--(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:G1))>0))),A1))^2`